# How to display xml with multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt

**I have an XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<document>
 <metadata>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">key1</field>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">link111</field> 
 </metadata> 
 <metadata> 
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">key2</field> 
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">link222</field> 
 </metadata> 
 <metadata> 
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">key3</field>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">link333</field> 
 </metadata> 
</document>
```

**And using XSL, the result should be -**

```
Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords   key1
Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url link111
Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords   key2
Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url link222
Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords   key3
Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url link333
```

I tried this, but it's not working on the second column -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <html> 
   <body> 
     <h2>Updated Tool Information:</h2> 
     <table border="1"> 
       <xsl:for-each select="document/metadata/field"> 
         <tr> 
           <td>Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td> 
           <td><xsl:value-of select="field/@name=MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords" /></td> 
         </tr> 
       </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
   </body> 
  </html>
 </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any thoughts how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried any XSLT yet? If so, can you edit the question to show what you have tried? Do note, you should use the `{ }` button in the editor to format any code you enter to make it readable. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working on the second column


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Updated Tool Information:</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="document/metadata/field">
    <tr>
      <td>Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="field/@name=MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Can you actually edit your question, and include your XSLT in the question itself (rather than in a comment), as it is easier to read. Just past in the XSLT, and use the `{}` button to format it as code so it can be displayed properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
<xsl:value-of select="field/@name=MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords" />
```

From looking at your expected output, it looks like you just want to output the value of the current **field** element, so perhaps you should be doing this

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html> 
      <body> 
        <h2>Updated Tool Information:</h2> 
        <table border="1"> 
          <xsl:for-each select="document/metadata/field"> 
            <tr> 
               <td>Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td> 
               <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            </tr> 
          </xsl:for-each> 
        </table> 
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice, it worked, The way I expect for the results. Thank you very much and pls bear with me on my post formats. In any case, thanks a lot and credit to your time.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, now I got the value of xml elements. Now how can I select specific xml elements to display only?


I'm using a match condition, so if there's a match, then the result will only show the active_url only -


Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url link111
Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url link222
Name: MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url link333





Appreciate any help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: My syntax is not working - 

<xsl:value-of select="@name = 'MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url/.'"/>

Comment: When using a match condition, you need to use square brackets around the condition. For example `<xsl:value-of select="field[@name = MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url]"/>`. If you still having problems, please ask a whole new question here on StackOverflow. Thank you!